# How to enforce case sensitivity when doing df.select in Snowpark

Tags: dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing a simple select on a dataframe
`dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("zstate") == 1).select(col("zuid"))`
which is failing because the table has been defined with lowercase column name and the generated SQL is converting `"zuid"` to `"ZUID"`. Is there a way to enforce case sensitivity in the generated SQL?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a different type of quotes around the double-quotes should help.

Try this:

```
.select(col('"zuid"')
```